# Making a program that determines the data type: How do I change the type of data I input?

Tags: python, types

I'm making a program that determines what **type** the input is (int, float or str), however I know that the input() function accepts inputs as strings so I'm a bit stuck.

```
stuff = input('Enter something: ')
print('Input is int?', stuff == int(stuff))
print('Input is float?', stuff == float(stuff))
print('Input is string?', stuff == str(stuff))
```

The above code is just to provide some context, it doesn't actually work though.

Or the more practical way:

```
stuff = input('Enter something: ')
print(type(stuff))
```

But it always returns `<class 'str'>` which doesn't always provide the correct answer e.g what if I entered "10"? Any ideas on how to change the type the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
stuff = input('Enter something: ')
try:
    # first you try an int, which is the most restrictive one
    stuff = int(stuff)
    print("It's an int")
except ValueError:
    # then you try a float which is less restrictive
    try: 
        stuff = float(stuff)
        print("It's a float")
    except ValueError:
        # if both conversions fail, it's a string
        print("Looks like it's a string after all")
```

Answer (score 0):

<class 'str'> means String. input() Always returns a string no matter what, to convert it you need to do the int(stuff) thing and if lets say i type 10b it will return error so i recommend that use a try catch phrase

```
try:
   int(stuff)
except ValueError:
   try:
     float(stuff)
   except ValueError:
     str(stuff)
```

Comment: that will throw an unhandled exception if the value cannot be converted to a float

Answer (score 0):

As you've realized, `input()` always returns a string. Since the type of the variable matters in equality checks, `stuff == int(stuff)` is never going to be `True` unless `stuff` is already an integer.

You could create a function that takes a sequence of types and tries to convert the input to each of those, and returns the result of the first successful conversion.

```
def convert_to(inp, types):
    for t in types:
        try:
            return t(inp) # Convert `inp` to the type `t` and return it
        except ValueError: pass # If fail, move on to the next type

    return inp # If nothing works, return the original input

stuff = input('Enter something: ')
val = convert_to(stuff, [int, float])
print(type(val))
```

Which gives the following output:

```
Enter something: abc
<class 'str'>

Enter something: 1
<class 'int'>

Enter something: 1.5
<class 'float'>
```

Note that you can check if `val` is an instance of any type using `isinstance()`:

```
val = 1
isinstance(val, int) # True

val = 1.5
isinstance(val, float) # True

val = 'abc'
isinstance(val, str) # True
```

Answer (score -1):

Try giving it a more direct variable, instead of just "stuff" that way you have limited options.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).